# ant warning: "'includeantruntime' was not set"

Tags: java, ant, build, javac, build-tools

I receive the following warning:

```
[javac] build.xml:9: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, 
defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 403):

## Ant Runtime

Simply set `includeantruntime="false"`:

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" ...>...</javac>
```

If you have to use the `javac`-task multiple times you might want to consider using [`PreSetDef`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/presetdef.html) to define your own `javac`-task that always sets `includeantruntime="false"`.

## Additional Details

From http://www.coderanch.com/t/503097/tools/warning-includeantruntime-was-not-set:

> That's caused by a misfeature
>   introduced in Ant 1.8. Just add an
>   attribute of that name to the javac
>   task, set it to false, and forget it
>   ever happened.

From http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html:

> Whether to include the Ant run-time
>   libraries in the classpath; defaults
>   to yes, unless build.sysclasspath is
>   set. It is usually best to set this to
>   false so the script's behavior is not
>   sensitive to the environment in which
>   it is run.

Comment: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010

Comment: so if you need the ant runtime in the classpath set it to yes/true otherwise to no/false. i guess you don't need it.

Comment: +1, Great answer. I just wish I could set that *once* somewhere in the buildfile instead of littering every javac call with it...

Comment: What does it any case it is set to True?

Comment: "Whether to include the Ant run-time libraries in the classpath; defaults to yes, unless build.sysclasspath is set. It is usually best to set this to false so the script's behavior is not sensitive to the environment in which it is run."

Answer (score 75):

As @Daniel Kutik mentioned, [`presetdef`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/presetdef.html) is a good option.  Especially if one is working on a project with many `build.xml` files which one cannot, or prefers not to, edit (e.g., those from third-parties.)

To use `presetdef`, add these lines in your top-level `build.xml` file:

```
  <presetdef name="javac">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" />
  </presetdef>
```

Now all subsequent `javac` tasks will essentially inherit `includeantruntime="false"`.  If your projects do actually need ant runtime libraries, you can either add them explicitly to your build files OR set `includeantruntime="true"`.  The latter will also get rid of warnings.

Subsequent `javac` tasks can still explicitly change this if desired, for example:

```
<javac destdir="out" includeantruntime="true">
  <src path="foo.java" />
  <src path="bar.java" />
</javac>
```

I'd recommend against using `ANT_OPTS`.  It works, but it defeats the purpose of the warning.  The warning tells one that one's build *might* behave differently on another system.  Using `ANT_OPTS` makes this even more likely because now every system needs to use `ANT_OPTS` in the same way.  Also, `ANT_OPTS` will apply globally, suppressing warnings willy-nilly in all your projects

Comment: Works great for retrofitting an existing Ant build file with multiple javac tasks. The presetdef element goes just inside project element.

Comment: @jwfearn: Can a similar `presetdef` trick be made to work for non-built-in Ant tasks? I've tried this with `scalac`, but because lower-down `build.xml` files have to manually define the `scalac` task, they override whatever I set at the top-level.

Comment: A note, that using presetdef will cause an ant warning that javac task has been redefined. Addind includeantruntime to each javac task avoids this. I am not aware of downsides of the warning. But this might be useful for people who 'need' clean builds.

Comment: Yes the presetdef gives "Trying to override old definition of task javac"

Answer (score 67):

[Chet Hosey](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=102399) wrote a nice explanation [here](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/warning-includeantruntime-was-not-set-tp2639463p2639765.html):

> Historically, Ant always included its own runtime in the classpath made available to the javac task. So any libraries included with Ant, and any libraries available to ant, are automatically in your build's classpath whether you like it or not.
>
> It was decided that this probably wasn't what most people wanted. So now there's an option for it.
>
> If you choose "true" (for includeantruntime), then at least you know that your build classpath will include the Ant runtime. If you choose "false" then you are accepting the fact that the build behavior will change between older versions and 1.8+.
>
> As annoyed as you are to see this warning, you'd be even less happy if your builds broke entirely. Keeping this default behavior allows unmodified build files to work consistently between versions of Ant.

Comment: I always thought this was the most silly feature/message ever. Who wants 'repeatable builds' in their configuration management tool? ;)

Comment: This answer seems to be the only one that tells us what the warning actually means.

Answer (score 27):

The answer from Daniel works just perfect. Here is a sample snippet that I added to my build.xml:

```xml
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
                                                 <!--   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  -->
        <classpath>
            <path id="application" location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
            <path id="junit" location="${lib.dir}/junit-4.9b2.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you like me work from commandline the quick answer is executing

```
export ANT_OPTS=-Dbuild.sysclasspath=ignore
```

And then run your ant script again.

Comment: This helps me *a lot*. I'm using `set ANT_OPTS=-Xms40M -Xmx512M -Dbuild.sysclasspath=ignore`.

Comment: Im facing an ant issue

Answer (score 6):

Use `<property name="build.sysclasspath" value="last"/>` in your build.xml file

For more details search `includeAntRuntime` in [Ant javac](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

Other possible values could be found [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/sysclasspath.html)

Answer (score -3):

i faced this same, i check in in program and feature. there was an update has install for jdk1.8 which is not compatible with my old setting(jdk1.6.0) for ant in eclipse. 
I install that update. 
right now, my ant project is build success.

Try it, hope this will be helpful.