# Use of the extension element 'redirect' is not allowed when the secure processing feature is set to true

Tags: ant, webdriver, junit4

Errors while applying transformations: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 Use of the extension element 'redirect' is not allowed when the secure processing feature is set to true.

I am using Junit-4 to run my test suite. when I run (ant) build.xml file  my test is exeucting properly but the transforming the xml output into HTML stuff is not working out.

- I've the "junit-frames.xsl" file in Reportstype directory.
- Junit version:   4
- JRE 7
- Ant 1.8.2

Please let me know how to get this solved ?

Thanks in advance.

Hanuman

Comment: possible duplicate of [Errors while applying transformations - Use of the extension element 'redirect' is not allowed when the secure processing feature is set to true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910092/errors-while-applying-transformations-use-of-the-extension-element-redirect)

Comment: Reportedly fixed by ANT 1.8.3. See: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51668

Comment: Thanks Mark. I got Ant 1.8.4 and that solved my problem.